# How to reduce size of buttons in mdbootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce default size of button but only the font size reduces. I want to reduce font size and button size in proportion.

I tried to reduce font button then the size was not in proportion to font.

Reference link: https://mdbootstrap.com/components/buttons/

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="standings">
    <div class="standingstitle">
        <h4>Teams Standings</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">See all stats</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-danger{
    font-size: 6px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Screenshot: (default size of button):

[image]

After trying above code gave me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the `padding` property in the default `btn` selector. Try this code.

```
.btn {
    padding: .4rem 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `.rem` much but can I use `px` also ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your selector more specific to prevent your rules from being overwritten:

```
btn btn-sm btn-danger {
    font-size: 6px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
}
```